# How do I read a closed excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a collection of .xls files in one folder. I wish to use VBA to extract values from these .xls while the files are closed.

Comment: Extracting data values from an Excel file will always require opening the file in some way. You can disable screen updating so your user will not see the process, among other options. VBA will work just fine for this, but you'll still have make a connection to the file (which will open it).

Comment: In the past, I've done it through Workbooks.Open which is slow. How do you open it in read mode? any other faster recommendation?

Comment: In vba, copy file to new location, open, read, close, delete.  That way original files are not touched

Comment: Without more details this Q is too broad to answer.  There certainly are ways to access data in an xls without opening it (ie without Workbook.Open 'ing it).  Which one would suit your case will depend on many factors

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with SQL then you can run queries against Excel files to get the data. It is much faster than opening an Excel file, but the data in your excel files needs to be well organized like a SQL table. Here is an example. 
[Write SQL query on excel tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525502/write-sql-query-on-excel-tables)

Answer (score -1):

```
Import data from a closed workbook (ADO)
```

If you want to import a lot of data from a closed workbook you can do this with ADO and the macro below. If you want to retrieve data from another worksheet than the first worksheet in the closed workbook, you have to refer to a user defined named range. The macro below can be used like this (in Excel 2000 or later):
GetDataFromClosedWorkbook "C:\FolderName\WorkbookName.xls", "A1:B21", ActiveCell, False
GetDataFromClosedWorkbook "C:\FolderName\WorkbookName.xls", "MyDataRange", Range ("B3"), True

```
Sub GetDataFromClosedWorkbook(SourceFile As String, SourceRange As String, _
    TargetRange As Range, IncludeFieldNames As Boolean)
' requires a reference to the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects library
' if SourceRange is a range reference:
'   this will return data from the first worksheet in SourceFile
' if SourceRange is a defined name reference:
'   this will return data from any worksheet in SourceFile
' SourceRange must include the range headers
'
Dim dbConnection As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim dbConnectionString As String
Dim TargetCell As Range, i As Integer
    dbConnectionString = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" & _
        "ReadOnly=1;DBQ=" & SourceFile
    Set dbConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    On Error GoTo InvalidInput
    dbConnection.Open dbConnectionString ' open the database connection
    Set rs = dbConnection.Execute("[" & SourceRange & "]")
    Set TargetCell = TargetRange.Cells(1, 1)
    If IncludeFieldNames Then
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            TargetCell.Offset(0, i).Formula = rs.Fields(i).Name
        Next i
        Set TargetCell = TargetCell.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    TargetCell.CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
    dbConnection.Close ' close the database connection
    Set TargetCell = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set dbConnection = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
InvalidInput:
    MsgBox "The source file or source range is invalid!", _
        vbExclamation, "Get data from closed workbook"
End Sub
```

Another method that doesn't use the CopyFromRecordSet-method

With the macro below you can perform the import and have better control over the results returned from the RecordSet.

```
Sub TestReadDataFromWorkbook()
' fills data from a closed workbook in at the active cell
Dim tArray As Variant, r As Long, c As Long
    tArray = ReadDataFromWorkbook("C:\FolderName\SourceWbName.xls", "A1:B21")
    ' without using the transpose function
    For r = LBound(tArray, 2) To UBound(tArray, 2)
        For c = LBound(tArray, 1) To UBound(tArray, 1)
            ActiveCell.Offset(r, c).Formula = tArray(c, r)
        Next c
    Next r
    ' using the transpose function (has limitations)
'    tArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(tArray)
'    For r = LBound(tArray, 1) To UBound(tArray, 1)
'        For c = LBound(tArray, 2) To UBound(tArray, 2)
'            ActiveCell.Offset(r - 1, c - 1).Formula = tArray(r, c)
'        Next c
'    Next r
End Sub

Private Function ReadDataFromWorkbook(SourceFile As String, SourceRange As String) As Variant
' requires a reference to the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects library
' if SourceRange is a range reference:
'   this function can only return data from the first worksheet in SourceFile
' if SourceRange is a defined name reference:
'   this function can return data from any worksheet in SourceFile
' SourceRange must include the range headers
' examples:
' varRecordSetData = ReadDataFromWorkbook("C:\FolderName\SourceWbName.xls", "A1:A21")
' varRecordSetData = ReadDataFromWorkbook("C:\FolderName\SourceWbName.xls", "A1:B21")
' varRecordSetData = ReadDataFromWorkbook("C:\FolderName\SourceWbName.xls", "DefinedRangeName")
Dim dbConnection As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim dbConnectionString As String
    dbConnectionString = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};ReadOnly=1;DBQ=" & SourceFile
    Set dbConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    On Error GoTo InvalidInput
    dbConnection.Open dbConnectionString ' open the database connection
    Set rs = dbConnection.Execute("[" & SourceRange & "]")
    On Error GoTo 0
    ReadDataFromWorkbook = rs.GetRows ' returns a two dim array with all records in rs
    rs.Close
    dbConnection.Close ' close the database connection
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set dbConnection = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function
InvalidInput:
    MsgBox "The source file or source range is invalid!", vbExclamation, "Get data from closed workbook"
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set dbConnection = Nothing
End Function
```

http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?d=envbadacimportwbado

&

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win024.htm